# How to handle lambda retries invoked from api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The api gateway url is triggered/called by a form submit. Now, as this is a synchronous invocation, how do I handle a lambda retries and handle throttles?

***Note:*** I am deploying api gateway along with lambda and use the url generated as webhook for form submit. So basically, it would be a one-way communication.

Flow:

```
form(payload)-> (api gateway)-> lambda-> lambda-> sqs-> lambda-> dynamoDb
```

Comment: I assume lambda is calling another aws service or 3rd party service, right?

Answer (score 1):

There won't be an automatic Lambda retry when it's invoked from API Gateway afaik. If you are throttled or the request fails (perhaps because of a Lambda function error), your client is responsible for deciding how to recover and whether or not to retry, likely based on the HTTP response code.

Also worth reading:

1. [A Detailed Overview of AWS API Gateway](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/api-gateway-elements/)
2. [How AWS Lambda Retry really works](https://enrico-portolan.medium.com/how-aws-lambda-retry-really-works-fb823e78b4a1)